# Jenkins Fails To Load file directory in centos

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, centos

mY selenium java code works fine locally and with Jenkins installed in windows, But when I am using my code in Jenkins how installed in centos Os I have this error:
    the file /var/lib/jenins/workspace/seleniumProject\resource\reportConfig.xml  was not found 
resource\testdata\edu_testdata_properties.yml(aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)

jenkins cannot find all directories with :  String PropertiesyamlFilePath = "resources\testdata\" + dataFileProperties;

when i change \ with / its work but the problem that I cannot execute the code locally in windows any idea plz?

```
 String dataFileProperties = "EDU_TestData_Properties.yml";
    String PropertiesyamlFilePath = "resources\\testdata\\" + 
 dataFileProperties;
```

Answer (score 0):

any path in linux is defined like this `/path/do/your/file.whatever` if you are trying to load it as you do on windows won't work.

You might want to return your file path based on the OS you are in.

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if (os.contains("win")){
    return "resources\\testdata\\";
}
else if (os.contains("osx")){
    return "resources/testdata/";
}      
else if (os.contains("nix") || os.contains("aix") || os.contains("nux")){
    return "resources/testdata/";
}
```